# vmware / centos extend disk

Tags: linux, centos, vcenter

I have some backups going to a mount point on a VM running centos below. I have extended the disk in vcenter and I can see the extra space, but I am not sure how to proceed with making this extra space usable.

I have looked into extending the different components but I think I am having a hard time finding the proper steps due to this being a mount point. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this without losing data?

sdc                             8:32   0  768G  0 disk
└─mysql_backup1-mysql_backup1 253:2    0  512G  0 lvm  /srv/mysql/backups

VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
mysql_backup1   1   1   0 wz--n- <512.00g      0

PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
/dev/sdc   mysql_backup1 lvm2 a--  <512.00g      0

LV            VG            Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
mysql_backup1 mysql_backup1 -wi-ao---- <512.00g

When I try to extend the LV I get an error that no space is available.